# How to call Oracle's olog()?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have a simple utility, which uses the "old" `olog()` method of connecting to Oracle database. I use it as described in [here](/a/48770162/1747834).

This works perfectly fine with Oracle client 8, but *crashes* (with `SIGSEGV`) when used with client versions 11 and 12. The server runs 11c and is the same in all cases.

The crash is deep inside Oracle's `libclntsh`.

The code was written based on demos included with client-8, but the sole demo included with client 12 does not use `olog()` at all -- apparently, `OCIEnvCreate()` and friends are the "wave of the future".

I don't want to rewrite my utility -- is there some simple way to keep using `olog()` by simply adding a step or two to the initialization?

*Update*: I added a call `opinit(OCI_EV_DEF);` prior to calling `olog()` and, instead of crashing, the program hangs inside the latter now...

*Update 2*: the hangs are due to OCI trying to operate (and lock!) stuff under `~/oradiag_foo`, which happens to be an NFS share. After configuring it, via `~/.sqlnet.ora` to use `/tmp/` instead, am back to crashing -- quickly.

Comment: Perhaps your `hda` no longer looks like a `ub1`, so you are actually invoking undefined behavior. There is currently not enough info to answer your question.

Comment: On the topic of demos, there are more OCI demos buried away on the DB demo install package.  Not so helpful, but that's the way it is at the moment.

Comment: @jxh, the `hda` is what it always was -- copied verbatim from the Oracle 8 demos: `ub4 hda[HDA_SIZE/sizeof(ub4)];` I do not use it in my code at all. Moreover, with Oracle 8 client, I can pass `NULL` instead of `&hda` and things continue to work perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out, the memory corruption I was hitting was elsewhere in my code (thanks, valgrind!)

I'm happy to report, the old method continues to work fine and no rewrites are necessary. The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48770162/1747834) I cite in my question is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

I can only encourage you to rewrite using the OCI8 API (which was introduced in 1998 or thereabouts).  There are newer wrappers around OCI8 that can make simple tasks easier.  See Oracle's https://oracle.github.io/odpi/ and Vincent Rogier's https://github.com/vrogier/ocilib

Comment: "_Use Y or Z instead_" is not an answer to the question "_How to use X_". My program needs to run in a _very_ restricted environment, where adding additional packages/libraries is so difficult, it is a complete non-starter.

Comment: It is, however, an answer on how to solve the business problem.

Comment: The joys of trying to share what little light I could.