# segmentation fault when try to connect oracle 19c database using olog() function

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface, oracle19c

I am using Linux8 environment and i have installed oracle 19c client. I have tried sample example of C program in which uses olog() oci function to connect to a remote database using
the client. when I execute the program with exiting database name(Giving database name in olog() function) then i am getting segmentation fault issue. If i am passing wrong database in **olog()** function then i am getting other issues, not segmentation fault.
below is the sample code:

//

```
    static Lda_Def lda;                                                  
    ub4      hda[HDA_SIZE / sizeof(size_t)];                        
    void logon();
    
    main(argc, argv)
    eword argc;
    text **argv;
    {

        
        printf("\nWelcome\n");

        logon();                                      

    }
    void err_report(cursor)
    Cda_Def *cursor;
    {
        sword n;
        text msg[512];                     

        if (cursor->fc > 0)
            printf("\n-- ORACLE error when processing OCI function %s \n\n",
                oci_func_tab[cursor->fc]);
        else
            printf("\n-- ORACLE error\n");

        n = (sword)oerhms(&lda, cursor->rc, msg, (sword) sizeof msg);
        printf("%s\n", msg);

    }
    void logon()
    {

        if (olog(&lda, (ub1 *)hda, (text *)"skills", -1, (text *)"skill", -1,
            (text *)"ORCLPDB", -1, OCI_LM_DEF))
        {
            err_report((Cda_Def *)&lda);
            exit(OCI_EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\n Connected to ORACLE as ocitest\n");

    }
```

```
 below is the error stack:
gdb) run
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5051992 in kpuhhaerr () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-323.0.1.el7_9.x86_64 libaio-0.3.109-13.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-28.0.1.el7_5.1.x86_64 numactl-libs-2.0.9-7.el7.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0 0x00007ffff5051992 in kpuhhaerr () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#1 0x00007ffff6f70f8b in ttcrbur () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#2 0x00007ffff6f51b40 in ttcdrv () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#3 0x00007ffff6f2157d in nioqwa () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#4 0x00007ffff6f02aa8 in upirtrc () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#5 0x00007ffff41cba55 in upirtr () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#6 0x00007ffff41c657f in upilgni () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#7 0x00007ffff51647ca in upilogc () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#8 0x00007ffff51646de in upilog () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#9 0x00007ffff50b20f7 in ocilog () from /oraclient/19.4.0.0.0/client/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#10 0x000000000040172c in logon()
#11 0x0000000000400d30 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf28)

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add references to the corresponding documentation and the example(s) you followed. What exactly is "Linux8"? Did you check that all function arguments are correct? See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/48999084/10622916 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/48715018/10622916

Comment: Thanks for replying.. i have followed this example https://github.com/alexeyvo/oracle_oci_examples/blob/master/oci19.c.

Comment: And i have followed both link whatever u have mentioned here. Please suggest me what exactly issue is there.

Comment: Why do you speak of _a segmentation fault_ when the error output says _SIGTRAP_?

Comment: By mistake , i have added output of SIGTRAP, now i have edited

Comment: segfault in memcpy means you have passed it an invalid source or destination.

Comment: thanks stark,  same code its working in windows 10. i am not getting any memory related issues.

Comment: @malakumari Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose. How exactly did you follow the linked questions? One of the answers suggests to use a newer interface instead of the outdated `olog`. I noticed that in the example on github, the function call `olog(&lda, (ub1 *)hda, (text *)"OCITEST", -1, (text *)"OCITEST", -1, (text *)0, -1, (ub4)OCI_LM_DEF)` conatins two times `(text *)"OCITEST"` and once `(text *)0` while your code contains three times `(text *)"skill"`. Is it intentional that you replaced the `NULL` pointer?

Comment: There is no guarantee that you will get an error message when your code contains memory access problems. If you have undefined behavior in your code, it may seem to run without problems in some cases and it may produce unexpected results or crash in other situations. If you don't get an error message in Windows, this can also mean that the system does not currently notice an error that may exist in your program.

Comment: Oracle OCI drivers install signal handlers for various Unix signals. So when you press Ctrl+C then the drivers 1st instructs database to stop evaluating the query. According to stacktrace `skgesig_sigactionHandler` it looks like some signal was trapped and then the application SEGFAULTed. Try to export this variable prior executing 
 `DIAG_SIGHANDLER_ENABLED=FALSE`

Comment: @Bodo, According to your suggestion, here i am passing three parameter like usernam,password and database name. so i have given third time skills. According to github example , Instead of database name ,here  its giving "0" .suppose if you will not give proper database name then you will get issues  like " 
ORA-12454: connect failed because target host or object does not exist".

Comment: @Bodo i have edited now, please help me to solve this issues.

Comment: I don't know anything specific about function `olog` and did not find a specification. I only noticed differences between the example and your code and suggested to double-check this. As we don't know your environment (e.g. database name, user name, password) it might help if you would explain the meaning of the function arguments and confirm that (how) you checked that these are correct. Links to the documentation would also be helpful. BTW: Your code uses deprecated K&R style function definitions. I suggest to use ANSI/ISO C style instead. Use `valgrind` or some other memory access checker.